# How to get a list of document IDs in a collection Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of documents with generated identifiers. The question is: is it possible to get a list of identifiers without querying all documents data? Is it better to store these keys in a separate collection?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The answer depends on which API you're trying to use.

For **mobile/web SDKs** there is no way to do what you're asking for since these clients [do not support projections of any kind](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/212).

For **server SDKs** you can do an empty projection, i.e.

```
db.collection('foo').select()
```

In this case the server will send you the documents that match, but will omit all fields from the query result.

For **the REST API** you can do the equivalent with a `runQuery` that includes a field mask of `'__name__'`, like so:

```
curl -vsH 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "parent": "projects/my-project/databases/(default)",
    "structuredQuery":{
      "from": [{"collectionId": "my-collection"}],
      "select": {
        "fields": [{"fieldPath":"__name__"}]
      }
    }
  }' \
  'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/my-project/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery'
```

Substitute `my-project` and `my-collection` as appropriate. Note that the `"collectionId"` in the `"from"` is only the right most name component. If you want keys in a subcollection the REST API wants the parent document name in the `"parent"` field.

Comment: Is there any way to order keys before select? I tried db.collection(...).orderBy(...).select().get(), but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This likely is better asked as a new question with what you tried, the results you got, and the results you expected. That said, it should work so long as the fields you want to orderBy are also in the fields you select.

Comment: It is possible that you need and index on the orderBy field before the query can be executed. In the web SDK you get nice error reporting this. Depending on how errors are being handled, it may not be coming through in Admin.

Comment: @GilGilbert would this REST API call count as a single query or would each document ID returned count towards the read quotas?

Comment: Each document you read counts, even if all you read is the document name.

Comment: @GilGilbert I'am not sure about the REST API, but the Admin SDK version should cost only one read per query. This is mentioned in the [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#other-queries).

Comment: @KrisztiánVelez: you're misinterpreting the documentation there. Getting document IDs is a counts as document reads.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#other-queries) documentation seems to indicate that for that query in particular, it only counts as one document read for the whole query, but in all other cases it is one read per document. Is that wrong?

Comment: It's phrased a bit confusingly, but what it says is that there's one **additional** document read charge for each read request.

Answer (score 21):

On node.js runtime you can get the list of document IDs like this

```
const documentReferences = await admin.firestore()
        .collection('someCollection')
        .listDocuments()

const documentIds = documentReferences.map(it => it.id)
```

Comment: You could use this to create an endpoint in your functions that your application can call and return a list of all your document ids.

Answer (score 0):

I had a need to fetch only ids without pulling fields of all documents in **Python**.

> I used [google-cloud-firestore 2.6.0](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-firestore/) package.

**select** and **field_paths** keywords were the very important part of this query. They allowed me to process without downloading all documents.

```
from google.cloud import firestore_v1

db = firestore_v1.Client()

items = db.collection("your_collection_name").select(field_paths=[]).get()
ids = [item.id for item in items]

print(ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some JavaScript and a little React code that seems to be working for me with the [V1 REST API's runQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/runQuery) using [client SDK bearer tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) in the browser (Chrome). This is patterned off of Gil Gilbert's answer. However, note that `parent` does not appear in [the body](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/runQuery#request-body) by the [structured query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/StructuredQuery), and unlike [some other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61114600/581848) on Stack Overflow, there is [no API key necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57029319/581848).

```
  const [token, setToken] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(setToken);
  }, [token]);

  const getCollectionAsync = useCallback(async collection => {
    try {
      if (!token) return [];

      const parent = `projects/${projectId}/databases/(default)/documents`;
      const url = `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/${parent}:runQuery`;
      const Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
      const headers = {Authorization, "Content-Type": "application/json"};
      const body = {structuredQuery: {from: [{collectionId: collection}],
        select: {fields: [{"fieldPath": "__name__"}]}}};

      const response = await fetch(url,
        {method: "POST", headers, body: JSON.stringify(body)});
      const json = await response?.json?.();
      return json;

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return [];
    }
  }, [cache, token]);
```