# How to get the id's for all documents without the data in a parsed collection in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get all the ids of all documents from a parsed collection **without** being charged for getting the document data. Will I be charged for receiving the data if I use this code below?

```
  db.collection("owners").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          console.log(doc.id);
      });
  });
```

This the database:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will be changed a document read for each of documents in the collection.  There's no way to do this without reading the documents.

[How to get a list of document IDs in a collection Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061903/how-to-get-a-list-of-document-ids-in-a-collection-cloud-firestore)