# Fetch all keys from Firestore collection with admin sdk

Tags: firebase, groovy, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I need to fetch all the ids/keys of a collection in Cloud Firestore. Currently I do it like this (groovy):

```
ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> snapshot = firestoreClient.database.collection(bucket).get()

List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.get().getDocuments()
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : documents) {
    keys.add(document.id)
}
```

I run this on a collection which potentially has could have a lot of documents lets say 30.000 which causes a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

The thing is that I don't need all the documents. As seen in my code all I need is to check which documents are in the collection (ie. a list of keys/id's), but I have not found any way to grab them with out fetching all the documents which has a huge overhead.

I using the Java Firebase Admin SDK (6.12.2).

So I'm hoping that there is a way to grab all the keys with out the overhead and without my heap maxing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `get()` will get you the full documents. But you should be able to do an empty selection. From the documentation for `select()`:

> public Query select(String... fields)
>
> Creates and returns a new `Query` instance that applies a field mask to the result and returns the specified subset of fields. You can specify a list of field paths to return, or **use an empty list to only return the references of matching documents**.

So something like this:

```
firestoreClient.database.collection(bucket).select(new String[0])
```

Also see:

- [How to get a list of document IDs in a collection Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061903/how-to-get-a-list-of-document-ids-in-a-collection-cloud-firestore)
- the Firestore Java reference documentation for the [`select` function](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/firestore/Query.html#select-com.google.cloud.firestore.FieldPath...-)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. No more overhead and excessive memory usage. I guess I still pay for reads for each document even though it's only the id I need, but I don't se any way around this.

Comment: I ended up with this: firestoreClient.database.collection(bucket).select().get().get().documents.collect{ it.id } which works perfectly

Comment: Thanks for confirming!