# Retrieve a list of documents, limited to IDs in an array -- follow up

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

This is a follow-up question to [the question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64327490/flutter-firebase-retrieve-a-list-of-documents-limited-to-ids-in-an-array). Long story short, I'm trying to limit a Flutter Firebase query only to values contained in a list.

Here's the working code with an additional question at the end. Using the 'shares' collection and adding an ID field to the 'projects' collection as below:

[image: Shares db]

[image: Projects db]

I'm now able to use one Stream to retrieve my shares (per user), and then use that list as a query in a second Stream like so:

```
@override
Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> getUserSharesStream({@required String uid}) {
  return _firestore.collection('shares').doc(uid).snapshots().map((doc) => doc.data());
}

@override
Stream<List<Map>> getListOfProjectsForUser({@required String uid, @required List<String> shares}) {
  var ref = _firestore.collection('projects');
  return ref
      .where('id', whereIn: shares)
      .snapshots()
      .map((QuerySnapshot snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) => doc.data()).toList());
}
```

In the app, I get a list of the projects shared with my user like so:

```
stream: userSharesQuery,
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    Map<String, dynamic> result = snapshot.data;
    projectsList = result.keys.toList();
```

By feeding that list into my `projectsListStream.builder` I get a list of the projects shared with my user, which was the answer to the original question.

My remaining question is: apparently I'm limited to 10 items in my query limit list. So how would ***YOU*** architect for instances where the number of shared projects is **GREATER** than 10?

Should I just abandon trying to limit my queries and simply parse the entire list of projects every time, looking for `projectIds` that match my user's share list? Or is there a way to call the stream more than once, each time with a list of 10? Or would you recommend an entirely *different* scheme for accomplishing the task?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late but I was trying to come up with something similar so this can help if someone wants to use snapshot instead of get to have a realtime stream

using [rx package](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) `CombineLatestStream.list` you can have multiple streams splitted with an array of lenght 10 or less and then combine them

```
@override
Stream<List<Map>> getListOfProjectsForUser({@required String uid, @required List<String> shares}) {
  var ref = _firestore.collection('projects');
  return CombineLatestStream.list<QuerySnapshot>([
   for(int i = 0; i < shares.length; i += 10)  //steps of 10, the maximum an array in WhereIn can handle
      ref.where(FieldPath.documentId,
         whereIn: shares.getRange(i,
           i+10 > shares.length ? i + (shares.length % 10) : i+10).toList() // at the end if the array is not a multiple of 10 return the remainder
         ).snapshots()
  ]).map((event) => 
    event.expand((qDocument) => qDocument.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) => doc.data())).toList()
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I will investigate and see if it helps in my situation.