# Firestore: is there a way to iterate through document_ID's without having to read?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Title gives the TLDR; version of the question. But I think the details below provide a better oversight of the situation.

---

- I have two collections `CollectionA` and `CollectionB`.
- `CollectionA` is accessible to all users, `CollectionB` is local to each user.
- `CollectionB` belongs to a user and consists of **document clones** of **n documents** housed in `CollectionA`. We create these cloned documents in `CollectionB` because we want user interactions, unique to the user, not to change the source found in `CollectionA`. In other words, the documents living in `CollectionA` need to be the blank slate originals in case other users someday come along and decide to interact with the documents (subsequently creating a clone of a document into their own respective `CollectionB`).

---

The question I'm wondering is what is the optimal way to write CRUD operations with the above pattern in mind. Specifically, I'm hung up on the best way to **Delete** a document in `CollectionA` and have it scan through and **Delete** all the matching cloned documents existing in users `CollectionB`. Note: Not all users may have cloned the "to-be-deleted" document, so it doesn't necessarily exist as a document on *all* users `CollectionB` collections.

My previous thought was to create a subcollection on `CollectionA`, specifically: `CollectionA/{DocumentID}/CurrentUsers/{UserID}`. Whenever a new user decides to clone a document they get appended to the `CurrentUsers` subcollection. Then, later if we decide to delete the document from `CollectionA` we can *first* iterate through that subcollection of UserIDs, then with each ID find the matching User, and delete the matching `CollectionB` cloned document (I figure they can share the same ID).

My concern with that approach is if 3,000 users have cloned this document, that first READ of the `CurrentUsers` would be 3,000 reads. I figure returning 3000 documents is a very large query. Obviously, it only gets worse if we scale up to 30,000 maybe worst case 3,000,000 users (am I close to a problem involving 3 million users? Not at all. But, I'd prefer to write a solution that scales well the first time!)

It *feels* like a good practice to write the `UserID`s of users to the `A` document's `CurrentUsers` subcollection. Though, this hinges on there being a way for me to simply iterate through the IDs of each of those documents to then find a matching User and delete their cloned copy. But, I don't know. Is there a better way to do this?

Thoughts?

-- hopefully that example made sense.

Comment: "is there a way to iterate through document_ID's without having to read?" Nope. While with the server-side SDKs and REST API you can [request an empty projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061903/how-to-get-a-list-of-document-ids-in-a-collection-cloud-firestore/47064719#47064719), and that way read only the document IDs, you'll still be charged a document read for each ID you read this way.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen honestly, I think I'm just pinching pennies here. I could create a shallow delete where I just delete the `CollectionA` document, which would probably be fine. Or in rare cases, do the 'deep delete" where I go through all that work mentioned above and delete the sh*t out of that document.  Thanks for the link though, kudos!