# Fetch only the document ids for documents that match a query in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I know I can retrieve the documents themselves with a query such as:

```
    const querySnapshot = await db.collection("records")
      .where("color", "==", 'blue')
      .get();
```

However this would presumably get expensive, and all I really need is the document Ids so that I can write to the documents. I don't really need to read their data.

So, how can I fetch only the document ids for documents that match my query?

Thanks

Comment: You can't. It's all or nothing.

Comment: In the Node.js SDK (which the Admin SDK wraps) this is possible with `select`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061903/how-to-get-a-list-of-document-ids-in-a-collection-cloud-firestore