# Check if firestore document exists without retrieving data

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

How do I check if a firestore document exists without retrieving it? Either retrieve the list of keys or go doc by doc, I know all the key names I’m checking for. But if I retrieve the entire collection it takes too long because each has a lot of data. Using python 3.9

Comment: Are you using Firebase Admin SDK or any client?

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the document to check if it exists even if you know the key and it will cost you a read.

Although if you are using Admin SDK then you can use projections so the data you fetch will be a single field or the document IDs only as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061903/how-to-get-a-list-of-document-ids-in-a-collection-cloud-firestore) which might help you save some bandwidth.

Comment: I'm not seeing how to get just the document ids using the admin sdk.  When I go to the python docs it basically just redirects me to the vanilla firestore client.  Should I be looking at the firebase_admin.db module?

Comment: @user433342 you are looking for [firestore module](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.firestore) When you fetch documents each of them will contain a DocumentReference from where you can get the ID. https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_document.BaseDocumentReference.id I'm not sure about python but in NodeJS it's like `doc.ref.id`