# send a firebase collection of the doc id's as an array through an endpoint

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

how od i send only the names of the documents in the collection through the endpoint?

```
  import { db } from '../../lib/firebase';


export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const user = await db
    .collection('readings')
    .get();
  if (!user.exists) {
    return res.status(404).json({});
  }

  return res.status(404).toArray(user.id);
}
```

I need to call the endpoint and then have the information sent to the frontend.
The collection of readings has a bunch of documents with all the account id's

how do I retrieve only the id's from the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying on a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference) that'll return all the documents in the collection so you cannot (and don't have to) use `exists`. Then you can just `map()` all documents IDs and send them back. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const qSnapshot = await db
    .collection('readings')
    .get();

  const documentIds = qSnapshot.docs.map(d => d.id)

  return res.status(200).json({ data: documentIds });
}
```

If you are using Admin SDK then you can also use `select()` to get Document IDs only. Checkout:

[How to get a list of document IDs in a collection Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061903/how-to-get-a-list-of-document-ids-in-a-collection-cloud-firestore)