# How to get a list of documents in a collection, without taking all the fields in the documents in firebase cloud firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get a list of the documents below in a list in the Cloud Firestore.

[image]

I have looked at
[How to get a list of document IDs in a collection Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061903/how-to-get-a-list-of-document-ids-in-a-collection-cloud-firestore) but it does not help me.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get a list of documents in a collection, without taking all the fields in the documents

When you read data from Firestore, you read the entire document, including all fields. There is no way you can only read only some fields. It's the entire document or nothing. Firestore listeners fire on the document level and this mechanism cannot be changed.

If you only need to read the values of two fields, for example, then you should consider storing **only** those two fields in a separate document. This practice is called [denormalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258303/what-is-denormalization-in-firebase-cloud-firestore), and it's a quite common practice when it comes to NoSQL databases.

Comment: How do i only add the document field instead of the entire thing into a list?

Comment: Simply by reading only the value of the field inside the document. You can do whatever you want with that field, even add it to a list.

Comment: How do I specify to only add specified fields to a list?

Comment: By calling the needed field separately. You might check the [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read). In Flutter it should be `Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;` and to get only the value of a field, use `${data['yourFieldName']}`.

Comment: I only know how to get the string of one field value, how do I get the value of the same field in multiple documents, and add each one to a list

Comment: You have to loop through the documents in the collection and get the desired value from each one of them.

Comment: So besides that, can I help you with other information?

Comment: Can you provide some example code? I'm still not sure sure how to do it

Comment: You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: So can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?